# What is the point of using a template as opposed to clonning a VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, clone, templates

I've red [this article published by VMware](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-B13C46B5-979C-4E41-9088-25AD78FF41B8.html) and [this blog post](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/vmware-template-creation) and neither actually explain what a template is. Why would one bother making and using a template, why not keep cloning a base image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically what a template is, a base image that doesn't change much.  Basically, marking a VM as a template just prevents it from booting up.  Think of it as your "gold" image that you can deploy multiple copies from.

You can always convert back to a VM to make changes, but templates make management a little bit easier.

Comment: Oh ok so the difference really is small, and in a sense is nontechnical because now everyone knows not to change it and wont get changed by accident?

Comment: Basically.  A clone makes an exact copy of a VM at the moment the clone occurs.  A template is a point-in-time image that doesn't change.